# Problem updating select field with data from API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm working with NextJS v13.4.7 w/ react and I'm trying to update data in a `select` field with data from an API call. When I first load the page, I set a default option field and value to the select field so it show's some instructions to the user
[image]

```js
// Creating the same json as my API output
let selectedDistricts = { "data": [{ dist_id: '0', name: 'Select a Province first' }] }
```

And I have a function to call an API once a separate field has selected a value and I think my problem is here as I'm trying to re-create the `selectedDistricts` with the output of the API data but this does not work and my API returns undefined

```js
function handleDistricts() {
  console.log('Province passed = ' + passedProvID)
  
  // I think my problem is here as I'm trying to re-create the selectedDistricts with the output of the API data - this does not work and my API returns undefined
  selectedDistricts = GetDistrictsAPI(passedProvID).then(data => {
    console.log('Province District Data is ', data)
    return data;
  });
}
```

BUT, if I give the API call a different variable name `districts`, the API returns the expected data

```js
function handleDistricts() {
  console.log('Province passed = ' + passedProvID)
  
  // I think my problem is here as I'm trying to re-create the selectedDistricts with the output of the API data - this does not work and my API returns undefined
  districts = GetDistrictsAPI(passedProvID).then(data => {
    console.log('Province District Data is ', data)
    return data;
  });
}
```

And where I get stuck at, is when I try to insert the json data into a select field

```js
return (
  <Field
    as="select"
    id="pxDistrict"
    name="pxDistrict"
    disabled={!values.pxProvince}
    onChange={(e) => {
      handleDistricts()
      setFieldValue('pxDistrict', e.target.value)
    }}
    className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
  >
    {selectedDistricts.data.map((p, i) => (
      <option key={i} value={p.dist_id}>{p.name}</option>
    ))}
  </Field>
)
```

Full file can be found here: https://github.com/TimLavelle/cv-patient-platform/blob/feature/registration/app/_utils/displayDistricts.js

What I'd rather not do is try to create two separate select fields based on the different data sets and am trying to find a way to use the same json object to map through the `option` fields inside the `select` field, but I can't figure out why I can't recreate the data using the same variable.

I'm sure it's a Next13 and/or other features I'm not fully across yet, but have tried a number of different things and thought it was time I posted here.

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions!

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in the code, in order to tell react that needs to reevaluate things you need to use a state, there are some unused variables and another important thing is that GetDistrictsAPI returns a promise so it doesn't matter that you saved it in selectedDistricts, you need to execute the code inside "then" to do it once the API call has finished and last but not least if you want to execute a code that has side effects or code that depends on state or props use "useEffect" passing an array with the variables that will be listened to re execute the code that is inside the useEffect

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
/* TODO: Fix the hook useProvinces inside the useMemo in order to have proper code */
import { Field, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import GetDistrictsAPI from "@/_utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export default function DisplayDistricts(props) {
  const { setFieldValue, values } = useFormikContext();
  let passedProvID = props.idProvince;

  const [selectedDistricts, setSelectedDistricts] = useState({
    data: [{ dist_id: "0", name: "Select a Province first" }]
  });

  const handleDistricts = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Province passed = " + passedProvID);
    GetDistrictsAPI(passedProvID).then((data) => {
      setSelectedDistricts(data);
    });
  }, [passedProvID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDistricts();
  }, [handleDistricts]);

  return (
    <Field
      as="select"
      id="pxDistrict"
      name="pxDistrict"
      disabled={!values.pxProvince}
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleDistricts();
        setFieldValue("pxDistrict", e.target.value);
      }}
      className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
    >
      {selectedDistricts.data.map((p, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={p.dist_id}>
          {p.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Field>
  );
}
```

Links related

- https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect
- https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vjf40F8O1AM (Promises, then, catch)
- https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory

Comment: Thanks @yuu. I'm getting some errors around 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleDistricts'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.' I'm going through your links and seeing what I can do fix this.

Comment: Thanks @yuu. This does fix that problem, but looks like I have another one to fix with a different API call now as well. I won't put that problem in here. Thanks!